# Move Xml Node by xslt

Tags: xslt

How to move the selected Xml Node to the last of the selected Node. below is a sample xml.

```
<Custom>
    <Root name="root1">
        <Folder name="Folder1">
            <Node name="Sample Node">
                <LevelGroup>
                    <Level name="1">First Level</Level>
                    <Level name="5">Fifth Level</Level>
                </LevelGroup>
            </Node>
        </Folder>
        <Folder name="Folder2">
            <Node name="Node A">
                <LevelGroup>
                    <Level name="1">First Level</Level>
                    <Level name="2">Second Level</Level>
                </LevelGroup>
            </Node>
            <Node name="Node C">
                <LevelGroup>
                    <Level name="4">Fourth Level</Level>
                    <Level name="5">Fifth Level</Level>
                </LevelGroup>
            </Node>
        </Folder>
    </Root>
    <Root name="root2">
        <Folder name="FolderA">
            <Node name="Node X">
                <LevelGroup>
                    <Level name="1">First Level</Level>
                </LevelGroup>
            </Node>
        </Folder>
    </Root> 
    <Root name="root4">
        <Folder name="FolderC">
            <Node name="Node Z">
                <LevelGroup>
                    <Level name="1">First Level</Level>
                </LevelGroup>
            </Node>
        </Folder>
    </Root>
</Custom>
```

in the above Xml, there are so many Nodes called "**Root**" and "**Node**". the "**Node**" has an attribute named "**name**". If the name attribute values Contains a string "Sample Node", then it has to move to last of the matched "**Node**". How can we achieve this by xslt.

below is the Expected result:

```
<Custom>
    <Root name="root1">     
        <Folder name="Folder2">
            <Node name="Node A">
                <LevelGroup>
                    <Level name="1">First Level</Level>
                    <Level name="2">Second Level</Level>
                </LevelGroup>
            </Node>
            <Node name="Node C">
                <LevelGroup>
                    <Level name="4">Fourth Level</Level>
                    <Level name="5">Fifth Level</Level>
                </LevelGroup>
            </Node>
        </Folder>
        <Folder name="Folder1">
            <Node name="Sample Node">
                <LevelGroup>
                    <Level name="1">First Level</Level>
                    <Level name="5">Fifth Level</Level>
                </LevelGroup>
            </Node>
        </Folder>
    </Root>
    <Root name="root2">
        <Folder name="FolderA">
            <Node name="Node X">
                <LevelGroup>
                    <Level name="1">First Level</Level>
                </LevelGroup>
            </Node>
        </Folder>
    </Root> 
    <Root name="root4">
        <Folder name="FolderC">
            <Node name="Node Z">
                <LevelGroup>
                    <Level name="1">First Level</Level>
                </LevelGroup>
            </Node>
        </Folder>
    </Root>
</Custom>
```

the change has to happen for

```
<Folder name="Folder1">
            <Node name="Sample Node">
                <LevelGroup>
                    <Level name="1">First Level</Level>
                    <Level name="5">Fifth Level</Level>
                </LevelGroup>
            </Node>
        </Folder>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the element you actually want to move is `Folder` and not `Node`

Anyway, I think all you have to do basically, is to set to `copy-of`-Lines. One for all those elements without your "sample string" as `@name`, one for those with. So, try the code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="Custom">
        <xsl:copy> 
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Root">
        <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:for-each select="@*"><xsl:attribute name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute></xsl:for-each>

            <xsl:copy-of select="Folder[not(descendant::Node[@name='Sample Node'])]"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="Folder[descendant::Node[@name='Sample Node']]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @Gururaj Venkatakrishnarao That's great! Can you please accept the answer?